# Input with spaces, shifting letters

Tags: c

I want to know how ro get input as is.

For example:

```
input: 1
       ab c
```

I want that the output will be:

```
       bc d
```

Code

```
  char x;
  int shift;
  printf("Please enter shift number:");
  scanf("%d",&shift);
  printf("Please enter text to encrypt:\n");
    while (scanf(" %c",&x)!=EOF)
    {
        if(x<='z' && x>='a')
        {
          x=(x-'a'+shift)%(NUM_LETTERS)+'a';
            printf("%c",x);
            continue;
        }
        if(x<='Z' && x>='A')
        {
          x=(x-'A'+shift)%(NUM_LETTERS)+'A';
            printf("%c",x);
            continue;
        }
        else{
          printf("%c",x);
        }
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a possibility that the user will type letters while passing a line until he clicks on CTR-z?

Comment: `" %c"` will disard spaces - i.e. only read non-space characters. Use `"%c"` as the format, or even better, read the characters with `getchar`.

Comment: I am sorry, but really cannot understand the question... What do you mean by *will type letters while passing a line*?

Comment: "I want to know how get input as is." With `fgets` which retains the newline too.

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes, it's possible. But here is a trick which you should notice:
`scanf` - returns number of actually read values. But you need to check whether the input was ended. For that use `getchar` function, for example, in your main loop.

Answer (score 1):

Changes needed

**Read a *line* for `shift`**

In preparation for the later `while()` loop, all of the `shift` input *line* needs consumption.

```
scanf("%d",&shift);
// add 2 lines to consume the rest of the line of input
// such as trailing spaces and \n
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

**Read, but do not skip white-space**

The `" "` in `" %c"` consumes without saving leading white-space.

```
// while (scanf(" %c",&x)!=EOF)
while (scanf("%c",&x)!=EOF)   // drop space from format
```

---

Style suggestion:
Rather than test for inequality of an undesired return value, test for equality of a desire return value.

```
// while (scanf("%c",&x) != EOF)
while (scanf("%c",&x) == 1)
```